# sum over $\frac{x^{k^2}}{k!}$ from $k=0$ to $\infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis, roots

One question that I recently am the following:
suppose I got the series
$
F(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{ak^2}}{k!}
$
where $a \in \mathbb{C}.$ I used Mathematica and check that this $F$ can not be written as some special functions of $x$. I want to ask what the root looks like if I vary $a$.

I know the following fact:
(1) if $a=0$, I got the $F(x)=e$ which has no root.

(2) according to Little Picard's theorem, I think any nonzero $a$ will definitely produce at least one root. But how many of them? Is there any way to attack such a problem?

(3) I know in general, finding a root for an infinite series is a very difficult task.

But I hope I can find a way to quantify it.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Can you repair $F(k)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{ak^2}}{k!}$ please

Comment: Sorry about this, I fixed to be $x$

Comment: What do you mean with $x^{ak^2}$ for $a$ complex ? $e^{ak^2 \log x}$ will produce different values for different branches of $\log x$. Anyway if you choose the same branch of $\log x$ for each $k$ then $F_a(x)= F_1(e^{a \log x})$ so we don't really care of $a\in \Bbb{C}^*$ (note that $F_a(x)$ will be entire only for $a\in \Bbb{Z}_{\ge 0}$)

Comment: Note that this series doesn't converge if $|x^a| > 1$, since $x^{k^2}$ grows faster than $k!$.

Comment: Right I missed that, it is never entire for $a\ne 0$